# Rails confuses loading of assets by js for actual route and processes it as controller action

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, audio

I'm trying to implement ion.sound in Rails 3.22
I can't get to have the sounds to be processed.
I parametered ion.sound to fetch the sound assets in "/app/assets", in my  js.coffee file like this :

```
# initialise plugin for ion sound
$ -> $.ionSound
    sounds: [
       { name: 'metal_plate' }
    ]
    path: '/app/assets/'
    preload: true
    multiplay: true
    volume: 0.5
# play sound
$ -> $.ionSound.play 'metal_plate'
```

but I noticed that the server trace indicates that it is conducting GETs on the sound paths and that Rails processes theses assets paths as controller actions, attempting to execute the corresponding actions which don't exist. Here is an exemple from the trace:

Started GET "/app/assets/metal_plate.aac?1476881187282" for 127.0.0.1     at 2016-10-19 14:46:27 +0200
Processing by DimensionsController#show as 
  Parameters: {"1476881187282"=>nil, "client_id"=>"app", "produit_id"=>"assets", "id"=>"metal_plate"}
Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/log_in
Filter chain halted as :signed_in_client rendered or redirected

so the result is a useless redirection and the sound asset isn't processed by ion.sound.

Answer (score 1):

1) place your sound resources in /public/sounds

2) in your .js.coffee

```
#initialise plugin for ion sound
$ -> $.ionSound
    sounds: [
      { name: 'metal_plate' }
    ]
    path: '/sounds/'
    preload: true
    multiplay: true
    volume: 0.2
```

3) in your .js.erb file:

```
ion.sound.play("metal_plate")
```

Answer (score -1):

URLs in the asset pipeline start with `/assets`, not `/app/assets`. The `/app` directory is not publicly accessible, you cannot link to files in there by their path.

If you have static files you want to serve to your front end, you should put them in `/public`, not `app/assets`.

Comment: thank you for your reply. It is unclear to me why certain assets should be placed in app/assets, such as javascripts, and others not, such as sounds...
As a matter of fact, I changed the ion.sound path to /public/sounds where I placed my sound assets, and Rails is still trying to process non-existant routes : Started GET "/castel_risques/espace_voyage/public/sounds/metal_plate.mp3?1476885168415" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-10-19 15:52:49 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/castel_risques/espace_voyage/public/sounds/metal_plate.mp3"):

Comment: Again, you are confusing the difference between the server-side path to a file, and the *actual public-facing URL*. You cannot expect your browser to access arbitrary parts of your file system! The URL for files in `public` is just `/`.

Comment: if I parameter ion.sound with path: '/sounds/', it is doing nothing at all. It doesn't even attempt to load the sounds. I get no error but nothing happens...